# Hibernate exception when try to launch Tomcat

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have application on spring-mvc+jpa. I build war and try to start on tomcat.

DataConfig:

```
import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class DataConfig {

    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "db.hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "db.hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROP_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "db.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        entityManager.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return entityManager;

    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));

        return properties;
    }

}
```

app.properties is:

```
#DB properties:
db.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb
db.username=root
db.password=111111

#Hibernate Configuration:

db.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
db.hibernate.show_sql=true
db.entitymanager.packages.to.scan=ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.model
db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create-drop
```

So, there is error message in tomcat logs:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:287)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>     ... 57 more Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection
>   cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set   at
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:97)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:170)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1818)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1776)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
>     ... 63 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't understand the properties you are passing it. You have `hibernate.dialect` defined as `db.hibernate.dialect` Remove the `db` portion and just have it as `hibernate.dialect` and do the same with your other hibernate related properties.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html

Comment: my other all properies must be without prefix db too?

Comment: only when it comes to key value mapping. Your non hibernate properties just are retrieving the value from your environment via the associated key such as the driver, username, url etc. but your hibernate you are specifying the key and value to set which is where its having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
```

This annotation value replace with below passing value

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties","file:config/application.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

and rebuild you project.now it's working fine.

Comment: Please explain your answer why this could solve the problem.

Comment: file:config/application.properties should be location of external application.properties file(Default location of file).some time IDE is not find the path of application.properties.That time also same error seen.